# Matlab: recursive algorithm to return the run count easily without profiler?

Tags: matlab, recursion, time, profiling

I would like to get the number of iterations that the recursive `mlfnonneg` requires. Currently, I use profiler for this but it would be more useful to get the number as a return value from the function. Is there any easy way to get it?

I measure the running time of a function like this

```
h=@() mlfnonneg(lb,ub,mlfBinCor,method);
tElapsed=timeit(h);
```

and now the function `mlfnonneg` should return the number of iterations. I have considered adding a ticker that the function always returns but I don't know how to get the return value after using `timeit`. How to get the running time and the running count of the recursive algorithm elegantly?

Comment: This is not a built-in Matlab function is it? So you can simply add it in yourself?

Comment: @mmumboss timeit is in 2013B and you can download it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function) to other Matlabs

Comment: No, I mean `mlfnonneg`

Comment: @mmumboss it is just an example, it could be any function such as `h=@() 1;`, just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can always add an optional return value to a function which you can use as a counter. Something like this:

```
[... count] = f(...)

% Do stuff here

if <some condition>
    % Recurse
    [... count] = f(...);
    count = count + 1;
else
    % Terminal condition
    count = 1;
end
```

You should just call your function one more time to get the count. This should not be a significant problem, since [timeit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function) actually performs multiple calls to your function to get an average metric.

Comment: One notice: do not run the counter over the timeit because it runs the code many times so you get unexpected number of runs. Calling the function one more time with global counter may be the easiest method.

Comment: @Floris. Why? This is MATLAB, not C. Also, it is always explicitly initialized.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I just realized you are calling this recursively - but the OP asked about iterations. I should have looked more closely at your example. I assumed that the function was keeping its own value of `count` from one call to the next. My bad.

Comment: @MadPhysicist this is for timeit function! So iterations are required.

Comment: Fun fact: I have literally no recollection of ever having answered this question or even a question like it. As far as I know, I am not senile.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an option for you - but you could create a global variable `IT_COUNT` that you declare both at the top level, and inside your function.

Before calling `timeit()` you set the variable to zero; inside the routine you increment it for every loop. When the function returns you print out the result - and there is your answer.

It does depend on you being able to modify the code to `mlfnonneg` to include the counter. I don't see an easy way around that, but maybe others have a better idea.

**update** inspired by Luis Mendo's (now deleted) answer that basically says the same thing, a bit more information.

In your `mlfnonneg` routine, add the following two lines (in a place where they are executed "once per iteration"):

```
global IT_COUNT;
if numel(IT_COUNT)==0, IT_COUNT = 1; else IT_COUNT = IT_COUNT + 1; end
```

This ensures that if you forget to create the variable at the top level, the code will not crash (you will thank me in the future, when you re-use this code and don't remember that you need a global variable...)

At the top level, add

```
global IT_COUNT
IT_COUNT = 0;
```

Then run your `timeit()` routine; finally use

```
fprintf(1, "The number of iterations was %d\n", IT_COUNT);
```

to get the answer you were looking for.

Comment: +1 I had just typed my answer when I saw you had already said it.

Comment: I think you need to replace `~exist('IT_COUNT', 'var')` by `isempty(IT_COUNT)`. When a non-existent variable is declared as global, it is created and initiallized to `[]`.

Comment: @LuisMendo - thanks again for pointing out my mistake. It turns out that `isempty` is false when a global variable is created (I just tried...). But `numel()==0` works. Updated example accordingly.

Comment: Weird... `isempty(IT_COUNT)` gives `true` on my Matlab version (2012b). Anyway, using `numel` is safer

Comment: I am using 2007b . Interesting. When I declare an ordinary variable `k=[]; isempty(k);` returns `1`. But `global K; isempty(K);` returns `0`. Yet `K` returns `[]`... I suspect this is an inconsistency that was "fixed" in later versions which is why I see this and you don't .